# Import-SPWeb with Overwrite always appends

Tags: list, import

I'm exporting a Custom List from one SharePoint instance and importing into another. The documentation says I should be able to use UpdateVersions with Overwrite to remove all items and then insert new data:

> *UpdateVersions*:
>
> Indicates how to resolve situations where a file to be imported to a
>   site already exists in that site. If the UpdateVersions parameter is
>   absent, the import operation by default uses a value of 1. 
>   The type must be any one of the following:
>
> -Add new versions to the current file
>
> -Overwrite the file and all of its versions (delete then insert)
>
> -Ignore the file if it exists on the destination The default value is Add new versions to the current file.

However, despite using the UpdateVersions parameter the data is always appended regardless. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell, you need to leverage the -Force flag.

```
import-spweb -identity $URL -Path "LINK_to_PATH" -Force
```

Comment: Hmm - still appended for me even with -Force param.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that versioning is enabled on your list. By default, versioning is turned off for most if not all list types.

Answer (score 0):

I finally removed my site and recreate it with default team site and import my production data to UAT environment